# Vectorise Numpy hsplit and vsplit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've written code that breaks down an image into smaller chunks that will be plotted and saved to a pdf file with Matplotlib. I've used numpy's `vsplit` and `hsplit` methods to break down the image as shown below:

```
n_rows = 2
step_num = 0
v_slice_list = np.vsplit(image, height/3)
    for slice in v_slice_list: # for each vertical slice
        cube_img = np.hsplit(slice, width/3) # further split into smaller chunk
        for i in range(0, len(cube_img), n_rows): # split into number of rows for plotting
            step_num += n_rows
            text = f'Lookup step {step_num} in dictionary'
            img_list = cube_img[i:i+n_rows]
            fig = image_to_pdf(img_list, n_rows, step_num, text)
```

Then I perform the plotting in the `image_to_pdf` function below:

```
def image_to_pdf(image_list, n_rows, step_num, text):
    fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    columns = 1
    rows = n_rows
    for i in range(1, columns*rows +1):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i)
        ax.imshow(image_list[0].astype(np.uint8), interpolation='nearest') # plot a single image
        ax.grid(True)
        ax.set_title('\n'*2 + 'Step ' + str(step_num - n_rows + 1), fontsize=12)
        ax.text(3, -3, f'Solution: {stext}', verticalalignment='top', fontsize=8)
    return fig
```

I'd like to know if I can use numpy vectorization to speed up the entire process. If not, what other ways can I speed up this code?

Comment: The `split` functions essentially do a `[arr[i: i+n] for i in range(0,N,n)]`.  That is they iterate over a range of values and take successive slices.  The key is that that they return a list of `views`.  In some cases those views all have the same shape, in others they can differ.

Comment: `sliding_window_view` might be useful https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html